drag and drop image it should display dynamically without refreshing page using ajax.but its not working for me
I need when i drag and drop the images its should display below form dynamically without refreshing the page and also front end and backend validation
view
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Drag and Drop File Upload</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.9.2/dropzone.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.9.2/dropzone.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">

<style>
  h3{
    text-align:center;
  }
  .image-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .image-container img {
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    margin: 10px;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid black;
  }
  .dropzone {
    border: 3px dotted #ccc;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-right: 200px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  /* Style the fallback input */
  .fallback {
    display: none; /* Hide the fallback input */
  }

</style>

</head>
<body>
<h3>Upload Images</h3>
<form action="<?php echo base_url('upload/image_upload') ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="fileupload">
<div class="fallback">
    <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
  </div>
</form>
<br><br><br><br>
<div class="image-container">
  <?php if (!empty($images)): ?>
    <?php foreach ($images as $image): ?>
      <img src="<?php echo $image['file_path']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['file_name']; ?>">
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>

</body>
</html>

model
    <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    use MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId;

    class upload_model extends CI_Model {

        protected $collection;

        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->library('mongo_db');
            $this->collection = 'uploads'; 
        }
        
        public function upload_image($data){
            if(isset($data['_id'])) {
                $data['_id'] = new ObjectId($data['_id']);
            }
            $this->mongo_db->insert($this->collection, $data);
        }

        public function get_all_images() {
            return $this->mongo_db->get($this->collection);
        }

    }

controller
    <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class upload extends CI_Controller {
        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->library('mongo_db');
            $this->load->model('upload_model');
        }

        public function index() {
            $data['images'] = $this->upload_model->get_all_images();
        
            $this->load->view('drag_drop',$data);
        }

        public function image_upload() {
            if ($_FILES) {
                $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpeg|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size'] = 5120;
            
        
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        
                if ($this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
                    $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
                    $product_image = $upload_data['file_name'];
                    $file_path = base_url('uploads/' . $product_image); 
                    $uploaded_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
        
                
                    $data = array(
                        'file_name' => $product_image,
                        'file_path' => $file_path,
                        'uploaded_time' => $uploaded_time,
                    );
                    $this->upload_model->upload_image($data);
                    
        
                
                
                }
            }
        }
        
    }

I need when i drag and drop the images its should display below form dynamically without refreshing the page
my database name:file_uploads
I'm using mongodb,codeigniter 3 and dropzone.js library
i need images present in db should display without refreshing the page

You would like to use the drag and drop API and AJAX for handling images, but you just posted a lot of PHP code and no JavaScript. You need to be more specific about the issue -- what is it that does not work? Is it your JavaScript or your PHP? Show your attempt to solve the issue.
